# Access to service overriding FOS User Bundle Controller

Tags: php, symfony, service, fosuserbundle

I'm new in Symfony2,
I'm trying to override a controller using a service inside

This is the register controller

```
class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
  public function registerAction(Request $request)
  {
    /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
    $formFactory = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
    /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
    $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');

    $user = $userManager->createUser();
    $user->setEnabled(true);

    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, new UserEvent($user, $request));

    $form = $formFactory->createForm();
    $form->setData($user);

    if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

            $userManager->updateUser($user);

            if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('easy_app_user_profile');
                $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            }

            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

            //create UserInfo
            $doctrine = $this->container->get('doctrine');

            $userInfo = new UserInformation();
            $userInfo->setUser($user);

            //save the userInfo
            $em = $doctrine->getManager();
            $em->persist($userInfo);
            $em->flush();

            //add user first login
            $loginManager = $this->get('user_login_manager');
            $loginManager->saveUser($request, $user);

            return $response;
        }
    }

    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.'.$this->getEngine(), array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
  }
}
```

near the end I'm using

```
$loginManager = $this->get('user_login_manager');
$loginManager->saveUser($request, $user);
```

But I can't use get because this is not extending Controller.
So I don't know how to access to my service in this controller

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->get('some_service')` is only a helper shortcut defined in the symfony base controller. Look at you code above and see how all the services are called:

```
$loginManager = $this->container->get('user_login_manager');
```

Btw. if you are using the latest version of FOSUserBundle (`dev-master`), then the [new event system](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md) might fit better than overriding the controller. `REGISTER_COMPLETED` may fit for you use case. If you take a look in the controller code above, you can see, when the event is dispatched. You should fairly use events than controller overriding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this works, I add an event event: 'security.interactive_login' but this only works on login and not on register that's why I'm adding this. If you have a solution let me know :)

Comment: In newer versions the FOSUserBundle has introduced own events on which you can listen. see the link in my edited answer